# Vue axios pass array as param to Rails and update all (bulk edit)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

In my Vue frontend I have set this method:

```
bulkAction(selected) {
  this.$secured.patch('/api/v1/bulk_edit', {
     data: this.selected,
     sold: this.bulk_sold
  })
    .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
});
    }
```

`selected: []` is an array of objects.
`sold` is a boolean and an attribute in the objects in the array selected.

So for instance if sold is true, I want to set sold as true for all objects in the array.

With this in place I am able to send to the server an array of objects(data) and a param sold.

In rails controller I have set this methd:

```
def bulk_edit
    @item_locations = ItemLocation.where(params[:data])
    bulk_params = params.permit(:sold)
    @item_locations.each do |item_location|
      item_location.update(bulk_params)
    end
end
```

Which returns:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `update' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x00007fa094596140>):
```

I guess this is the wrong part:

```
    @item_locations = ItemLocation.where(params[:data])
```

But I'm not sure on how to convert it.

The request looks like:

```
    app/controllers/api/v1/items_controller.rb:47:in `bulk_edit'
Started PATCH "/api/v1/bulk_edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-01-20 16:40:28 +0800
Processing by Api::V1::ItemsController#bulk_edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"data"=>[{"id"=>"44ed3183-cce2-4f3b-b673-6052d8cc5fe5"}, {"id"=>"ed7438dc-60ed-4887-bf86-90b6161c0074"}], "sold"=>false, "item"=>{}}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You must first get those records as ActiveRecord objects in invoke update on them. Otherwise you're just trying `update` what you receive from the request, which is converted into an `ActionController::Parameters` object.

Comment: What's the identifier you're sending (`params[:data]`) in order to query the records from the DB?

Comment: Could you show how to convert it in an answer?

Comment: @SebastianPalma it's id

Comment: But if I can't convert the objects and I have to iterate to covert to Active Record at that point I can just pass the ids instead of the objects.

Comment: Sure, do you have an example of what you're sending. The patch body?

Comment: I have updated with the patch body

Comment: Try with `Location.where(id: params[:data].map { |location| location[:id] }).update(sold: params[:sold])`

Comment: Are you also updating every location item?

Comment: @SebastianPalma I have updated the question. In the request I am passing now ids only. So I need to update ItemLocation with id as the ones in the array passed.

Comment: You can try something similar: `ItemLocation.where(id: params[:data].map { |item_location| item_location['id'] }).update_all(sold: params['sold'])`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma thanks a lot it works! If you put in an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what you're sending, you need to first map what goes inside `data` in order to get each ItemLocation id, so you can make an `IN` query:

```
ItemLocation
  .where(id: params['data'].map { |item_location| item_location['id'] })
  .update_all(sold: params['sold'])
```

After that, you can use `update_all` to perform a single query to update every ItemLocation you got, with the value of sold equals to what's in the params,

Answer (score 0):

Tried to simplify it

```
def bulk_edit
    @item_locations = ItemLocation.where(id: params[:data]).update_all(params.permit[:sold])
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this returns no records to update..

Comment: You need to map what comes in `params[:data]`. `where` doesn't automatically retrieve the content from it.

Comment: TS said that he has updated request body and now sends only array of ids. So I suppose we can do where on them. Or I misunderstood something